# Add a file to archives in a folder between 2 specific sizes

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, filesize

I am trying to add information.txt to all .rar files between 11534336 bytes and 22020095 bytes in a folder. I wrote the code below but it adds the text file to all the rar files within the folder. I am not sure what is wrong with the script.

```
@REM ------- BEGIN mod.bat ----------------
@setlocal
@echo off
set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\";%path%
for /F %%I in ('dir /b *.rar') do (
    IF 11534336 LEQ %%~zI IF %%~zI LEQ 22020095 do ( 
        rar a -m0 %%I "information.txt"
     )
)
REM ------- END mod.bat ------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF 11534336 LEQ %%~zI IF %%~zI LEQ 22020095 do ( 
                    The problem is here ----^^
```

`IF` command does not include a `do` clause as the `for` command. What you are executing is equivalent to

```
for /F %%I in ('dir /b *.rar') do (
    IF 11534336 LEQ %%~zI IF %%~zI LEQ 22020095 do 
    ( 
        rar a -m0 %%I "information.txt"
    )
)
```

That is, for all the files, execute the `rar` command, and for the files that match the condition, call the `do` command, that probably does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

May your file names have spaces? If so, then this line:

```
for /F %%I in ('dir /b *.rar') do (
```

should be written this way:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b *.rar') do (
```

However, in this case the `for /F` is not needed (and is the cause of the problem, indeed), so I suggest you to use the forgotten plain `for` command instead:

```
for %%I in (*.rar) do (
```

Answer (score 0):

un-do your if.

```
IF 11534336 LEQ %%~zI IF %%~zI LEQ 22020095 (
```

Although

```
IF %%~zI GEQ 11534336 IF %%~zI LEQ 22020095 (
```

is probably more intuitive - but the same thing.

(and it would have been a lot easier had you mentioned what error you were getting)